# While loop indents after second try for getting correct user input

Tags: python, while-loop, formatting, indentation

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from colortroop import *


while True:
    try:
        start1 = input(bright_transparent_colors.blue +
                       "1st Start Time: "+colors.reset)
        s1 = datetime.strptime(start1, "%H:%M")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(italic_transparent_colors.red +
              "You have used the wrong format! The correct format is "+bright_transparent_colors.red+"XX:YY!"+colors.reset)

while True:
    try:
        end1 = input("1st End Time: ")
        e1 = datetime.strptime(end1, "%H:%M")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You have used the wrong format")


delta1 = e1 - s1

print(delta1)
print(
    f"{str(delta1).split(':')[0]} Hours and {str(delta1).split(':')[1]} Minutes")
```

Now when I run it I get the ability to give input, I format it wrong or spell it wrong, I get an error message, and when it asks for input again, it is indented!

Why does it indent it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Help us help you - please share your code as formatted text, not as an image.

Comment: What is this `colortroop` module?

Comment: When I remove the `colortroop` import and all associated variables, your loops print and run fine. Nothing is indented. And I'm not able to find any python package called 'colortroop'. Is it something "internal" to where you work/study? Check the docs on what exactly `colors.reset` does. Also, the terminal/console you're using may not be dealing well with the colour-codes and creating extra whitespace or something.